# Return dropbox as a partialview based on selection of another dropbox

Tags: .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

Controller code:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
        {
            ViewBag.Cat_ID = new SelectList(_context.Category, "Cat_ID", "Cat_Name");
            var specialists = await userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("Specialist");
            ViewBag.Specialist_ID = new SelectList(specialists, "Id", "UserName");
            return Request.IsAjaxRequest() ? (IActionResult)PartialView() : View();
        }
```

Dropbox controller code:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult CreatePopulateSCat(string CatID)
        {
            List<SubCategory> AllSubCategories = _context.SubCategory.ToList();
            List<SubCategory> SelectedSubCategories = AllSubCategories.FindAll(a => a.SCat_Cat.Contains(CatID));
            ViewBag.SCat_ID = new SelectList(SelectedSubCategories, "SCat_ID", "SCat_Name");
            return Request.IsAjaxRequest() ? (IActionResult)PartialView("CreatePopulateSCat") : View("Create");
        }
```

Create.cshtml:

```
            <select id="SCat_Cat" name="SCat_Cat" asp-for="Cat_Id" asp-items="(SelectList)ViewBag.Cat_ID" class="form-control" onchange="funct()">
                <option value="0">Pasirinkite kategoriją</option>
            </select>
@Html.Partial("CreatePopulateSCat", Model)
```

ajax code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function funct() {
        var catvalue = document.getElementById("SCat_Cat").value;
        var url = "CreatePopulateSCat"
        alert(catvalue);
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "GET",
                url: url,
                data: { CatID: catvalue },
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.success) {
                        alert("Good");
                        document.getElementById("SCat_SCat").innerHTML = result;                     
                    }
                },
                error: function (req, status, error) {
                    alert(error);
                }
            });
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

I've tried many different iterations of this, and usually I was thrown back an error saying Root element not found, this iteration actually activates the controller code, but it doesn't return either the "success" or "error" code in ajax script. Just nothing happens.

I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: `alert("Good");` or `alert(error);` any of those js executes?

Comment: Yes they are Js executes.

Comment: Then you are getting data from the controller. What do you see if you write `console.log(result)` in the success message?

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread the question, No they don't execute. Excuse me.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `IActionResult` type object from the `CreatePopulateSCat(string CatID)` Action. but in the UI you are trying to read `result.success`. `IActionResult` has got no `success` property. So your js will not work anyways.

If you are trying to work with JSON object then why not return a JSON object from the controller instead? The rendered view html can be a property of the json.

```
return Json(new { success = true, result = "ViewResult" });
```

Comment: Okay, we have progress, I get the success alert but the dropbox doesn't get populated now.
`document.getElementById("SCat_SCat").value = result;` this probably won't cut it, right?

Comment: Thank you by the way, sorry if I seem rude, I'm just excited to finally fix the problem haha

Comment: This will not work the same reason mentioned in the answer. IActionResult cannot be put in the dropdon. You need to add `<option value=""></option>` elements to the "SCat_SCat" object.